# Error - required framework not installed - Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, uwp

I reset my PC, and then I opened my uwp app, and I suddenly get this error, it was not there before, now only, please help.

This is a very critical issue for me I have been working on my app for more than a year.

> Error
> DEP0800: The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop\14.0.\AppX\Debug\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx" failed to install. [0x80070005]    Levi OS 1.0

Comment: Have you installed the required SDK and Restored Nuget Packages , also remove old debug files

Comment: Do “Clean” and then “Build” again

Comment: Have you tried to get `Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx` package with above path and reinstall it. It's c++ desktop runtime package.

Comment: how to reinstall it @Nico Zhu

Comment: I went to that path and instaled it through .appx file but it showed "Access is denied. (0x80070005)"

Comment: login with admin and find the appx and double click it.

Comment: @LeviIsrael, Do you install the appx successfully ?

Comment: yes thanks a lot it worked. would you mind posting it as an answer and I'l mark as answer?

Comment: I don't know, may your the description of topic is not clear. I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error - required framework not installed - Visual studio C#

Please try to get Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.Desktop.appx package with above path and reinstall it. It's c++ desktop runtime package.  If you viewed  "Access is denied. (0x80070005)" error, please try use admin account to do above steps.